# Parsing two-dimensional text

Tags: regex, text, text-parsing

I need to parse text files where relevant information is often spread across multiple lines in a nonlinear way. An example:

```
1234
 1         IN THE SUPERIOR COURT OF THE STATE OF SOME STATE           
 2              IN AND FOR THE COUNTY OF SOME COUNTY                
 3                      UNLIMITED JURISDICTION                        
 4                            --o0o--                                 
 5                                                                    
 6   JOHN SMITH AND JILL SMITH,         )                             
                                        )                             
 7                  Plaintiffs,         )                             
                                        )                             
 8        vs.                           )     No. 12345
                                        )                             
 9   ACME CO, et al.,                   )                             
                                        )                             
10                  Defendants.         )                             
     ___________________________________)
```

I need to pull out Plaintiff and Defendant identities.

These transcripts have a very wide variety of formattings, so I can't always count on those nice parentheses being there, or the plaintiff and defendant information being neatly boxed off, e.g.:

```
 1        SUPREME COURT OF THE STATE OF SOME OTHER STATE
                      COUNTY OF COUNTYVILLE
 2                  First Judicial District
                     Important Litigation
 3  --------------------------------------------------X
    THIS DOCUMENT APPLIES TO:
 4
    JOHN SMITH,
 5                            Plaintiff,          Index No.
                                                  2000-123
 6
                                            DEPOSITION
 7                  - against -             UNDER ORAL
                                            EXAMINATION
 8                                              OF
                                            JOHN SMITH,
 9                                           Volume I

10  ACME CO,
    et al,
11                            Defendants.

12  --------------------------------------------------X
```

The two constants are:

1. "Plaintiff" will occur after the
   name of the plaintiff(s), but not
   necessarily on the same line.
2. Plaintiffs and defendants' names
   will be in upper case.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the numbers on the left? Did you add these or are they part of the source? You say that Plaintiff will be Uppercase but "JOHN SMITH and JILL SMITH" contains lower case letters. What are the possible characters between the plaintiff name and the "Plaintiff" text? Is it purely white space, parentheses and commas?

Comment: These are line numbers that are part of the source. 
I've corrected the capitalization of the plaintiffs' names. 
Between plaintiff name and and "Plaintiff" can be really anything. Just non-alphabet characters and white space is NOT guaranteed.

Comment: You could always use a neural network. Those work well for text parsing: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/No,_We_Need_a_Neural_Network.aspx

Comment: I think I might have to apply some machine learning: it's difficult for me to convey how inconsistent these transcript files are. You've all submitted very nice solutions to the examples I've posted, but for every special case you handle, I can find three more transcripts (written by different transcription companies, of course) that violate and break your solution. 

I'm thinking about boosting a simple lexical parser.

Comment: People kinda looked at your two examples and said "I can do that" instead of seeing the general problem, which is really hard (at least N^3 hard!). I immediately thought: gotta get the text into two-D array so you can detect the "islands". Anyway, just for my own future reference, I point to this MS research paper: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/69347/docgeom_icdar2005.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754173/parsing-two-dimensional-text/2754352#2754352).
Here's perhaps a more general approach using [Python](http://www.python.org/):

```
import re

# load file into memory 
# (if large files, provide some limit to how much of the file gets loaded)
with open('paren.txt','r') as f:
  paren = f.read() # example doc with parens

# match all sequences of one or more alphanumeric (or underscore) characters 
# when followed by the word `Plaintiff`; this is intentionally general
list_of_matches = re.findall(r'(\w+)(?=.*Plaintiff)', paren, 
    re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)

# join the list separating by whitespace
str_of_matches = ' '.join(list_of_matches)

# split string by digits (line numbers)
tokens = re.split(r'\d',str_of_matches)

# plaintiffs will be in 2nd-to-last group
plaintiff = tokens[-2].strip()
```

Tests:

```
with open('paren.txt','r') as f:
  paren = f.read() # example doc with parens
list_of_matches = re.findall(r'(\w+)(?=.*Plaintiff)',paren,
  re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
str_of_matches = ' '.join(list_of_matches)>>> tokens = re.split(r'\d', str_of_matches)
tokens = re.split(r'\d', str_of_matches)
plaintiff = tokens[-2].strip()
plaintiff
# prints 'JOHN SMITH and JILL SMITH'

with open('no_paren.txt','r') as f:
  no_paren = f.read() # example doc with no parens
list_of_matches = re.findall(r'(\w+)(?=.*Plaintiff)',no_paren,
  re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
str_of_matches = ' '.join(list_of_matches)
tokens = re.split(r'\d', str_of_matches)
plaintiff = tokens[-2].strip()
plaintiff
# prints 'JOHN SMITH'
```